# Split a list into groups based on index of elements

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I have a collection (a stream), and want to make it a stream of even and odd index elements Ex.
"slow" -> "solw" or "lwso"

```
fun part2(s: String) = s
  .withIndex()
  .groupBy { it.index % 2 }.values
  .flatMap { it.map { v -> v.value } }
```

I learned `withIndex` lately, of course i could use `mapIndexed`. But no matter what I do, i need last step of `v.value` sort of. I wonder if there's any other way of writing simple things like this in `kotlin`.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `n` with `2`

```
fun part(s: String, n: Int): String = s
    .withIndex()
    .groupBy(keySelector = { it.index % n }, valueTransform = { it.value })
    .flatMap { it.value }
    .joinToString(separator = "")
```